# Rigify extreme deformations

Tags: rigging, weight-painting, rigify

I've seen many rigify questions on this site, but none that explain something to this extreme. This model is freshly rigged with rigify. Any minor change in pose causes a large deformation, and nothing is consistent from any video or tutorial I have been following. 
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

I understand weight paint, but it only seems to make the problem worse by introducing new ones.

[To the blend file](http://www.megafileupload.com/en/file/559289/RiggedFresh-blend1.html)

Thank you for your help, and I hope something can be done about it. There is another model suffering from the same problems.

Comment: It **IS** the weight painting.

Comment: @Laina Also, Copyrights...

Comment: @someonewithpc I know where it's from, and I never claimed it was mine. It's a solid model for practice.

Comment: @Laina I just want to make sure you realize it's copyrighted, and you might (not really gonna happen)  get in problems.

Comment: @someonewithpc I do appreciate the concern. Thank you! And too many take advantage of material that isn't theirs so I would say the same thing you did. Wanted to use a good control model to experiment with to try to solve some problems.